# WordPress Multisite subdomains RewriteRules .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, multisite

I want to redirect some old urls to new one and I want this also for the subdomains, but I've a hard time to get this work. Do I miss something in my `.htaccess`? The redirects won't work for my main site but also the sub domains doesn't work.

**And a another question.**

If I want to redirect subdomains, but the subdomains have been `domain mapped`, example `sub.domain.com => anotherdomain.com`, do I have to use the original SUB domain for redirects or do I use the mapped domain?

This is my `.htaccess`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wp/$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wp/$2 [L]
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Redirects of main site `main blogsite`**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [nc]

#Redirect 'domain.com/about_us.html' to 'domain.com/about-us'
RewriteRule ^about_us\.html$ /about-us/ [R=301,L]
```

**Redirects for subdomains**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^anotherdomain\.com [nc]

#Redirect 'anotherdomain.com/projects.html' to 'anotherdomain.com/projects/summary/'
RewriteRule ^projects\.html$ /projects/summary/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: if you're not sure if the htaccess is working, why not test it with this [tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/).